# UIPickerView - conditional display

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, user-experience

I am very new to swift and have a question on UIPickerView.

I have created two pickerviews

One with values - A, B, C, F

Two with values - B, C, D, E

and I now want a logic to be implemented in these two pickerviews.

The logic is that if B and C are chosen in the first pickerview then the second pickerview won't have B and C for the user to choose.  How could I achieve that?

I am a beginner to swift so any hints would be appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var Picker1: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var Picker2: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var savedVal1 = "" as String
    var savedVal2 = "" as String

    var Array = ["A", "B", "C", "F"]
    var Array2 = ["B", "C", "D", "E"]

    var PlacementAnswer = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Picker1.delegate = self
        Picker1.dataSource = self
        Picker1.tag = 1

        Picker2.delegate = self
        Picker2.dataSource = self
        Picker2.tag = 2
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == Picker1
        { return Array[row] }
        else if pickerView == Picker2
        { return Array2[row] }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if pickerView == Picker1
        { return Array.count }
        else if pickerView == Picker2
        { return Array2.count }
        return 1
    }

    func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the selection delegate function for your `pickerView` with:

```
var array3 = Array2 //Create a copy of Array 2

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    //Check if picker is picker1 and the chosen value is "B" or "C"
    if pickerView == Picker1 {
        if Array[row] == "B" || Array[row] == "C" {
            //Check if "B" and "C" is available
            if let index = Array2.indexOf(Array[row]) {
                //Remove it from Picker2 datasource array and reload it
                Array2.removeAtIndex(index)
                Picker2.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
        else {
            //If choose another option other than "B" and "C", revert back to the first array
            Array2 = array3
            Picker2.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
}
```

And honestly you should read about Swift code invention, variable should be lowercase, not uppercase

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Just a question - on this command "Array2.removeAtIndex(Array2.indexOf(Array[row]))" I have an error message - "value of optional type 'index?' not unwrapped, did you mean to use '!' or '?' "

Comment: ah sorry i just write it without compiler so you can just follow the fix by the system and add `!`

Comment: thank you SO much.  Another issue came up - After I select a value in the first pickerView, the corresponding value in the second pickerView is deleted.   When I reselect the same value in the first pickerView, an error came up.

Answer (score 0):

One of ways, when a user will not be confused what really happens is not to delete items from the picker. Rather show him what you really mean, he would understand better that the options are not available at certain combination. The solution can be even more simple.

Description: User selects B or C from first picker. Then, if B or C in second picker is selected, it **jumps to the next available option**.
Additionally, we could change the color of rows, that are unavailable.

```
//REMOVED METHOD - not able to change title color
/*func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    if pickerView == Picker1
    { return Array[row] }
    else if pickerView == Picker2
    { return Array2[row] }
    return ""
}*/

//ADDED METHOD - for styling of your UIPickerView title
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {

    let string = pickerView == Picker1 ? Array[row] : Array2[row]

    if (pickerView == Picker2 && (row == 1 || row == 2)) {
        return NSAttributedString( // gray row, when B or C in Picker2
            string: string,
            attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray]
        )
    }

    return NSAttributedString( // common row
        string: string,
        attributes: nil)
}

//UPDATED METHOD - to reset second picker if user selects B or C from the second picker
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if (pickerView == Picker1 && (row == 1 || row == 2)) {
        print("You selected B or C in first PickerView")
    } else if (pickerView == Picker2 && (row == 0 || row == 1)) {
        // if already set B or C in first Picker, and user has selected B or C in second picker,
        // jump to the next available option
        Picker2.selectRow(3, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the code in Swift 3.0, so if you copy&paste, you should update the code to previous Swift version.